Ноутбук не загружается с загрузочной флешки
На ноуте стоит 10 винда, хочу поставить убунту. Скачал образ с официального сайта, поставил его на флешку через Rufus. Но после выбора в биосе загрузки с загрузочной флешки всё равно загружается винда, никаких информационных сообщений нет. Проверил на компе - всё отлично работает. В чём может быть причина? Secure boot выключен. На ноуте в boot меню флешка отображается как UEFI: General UDisk 5.00, Partition 1, хотя флешка называется не так. Может в этом какая-то причина? Хотя на компе, повторюсь, всё работает хорошо, уже не раз переустанавливал систему.

Для того, чтобы комп начал стартовать не с устройства по умолчанию, это надо указать в соответствующем разделе настроек в БИОС. Кроме того,  большинство современных компов позволяет не настраивать этот параметр, но стартовать с нужного устройства с помощью меню доступных вариантов загрузки, вызываемого на старте при нажатии клавиши F12. Не знаю, понимает ли Убунту что такое UEFI. если не понимает, то такой режим тоже должен быть изменён на нечто типа Legacy. Все БИОС разные, конкретный рецепт нельзя дать, но почти во всех есть настройки загрузки.

Это сложные вещи, если нет знаний, лучше обратитесь за помощью к специалисту.

@FoxFox в моём биосе почему-то нет возможности сменить на legacy. Когда выбирают флешку через F12 и нажимаю Enter, экран моргает и снова передо мной окно выбора средства загрузки

На ноуте в boot меню флешка отображается как UEFI: General UDisk 5.00, Partition 1, хотя флешка называется не так. скорее всего просто это не флешка. ищите меню "порядок загрузки" и там тасуйте пункты так, чтоб флешка оказалась выше всех. по хорошему, даже без возникновения подобных проблем лучше всего перед попыткой установки новой ОС, накопитель со старой выдернуть, поставив на его место новый, пустой. если с новой ОС что-то пойдёт не так(а на ноутах с этим вечно хоть что-то да не так) - втыкание старого накопителя вернёт старую ОС безо всяких плясок с бубном.

Проблема решилась с помощью установки через Ventoy.
